# Matrix exponential with given Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix exponential for the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
-14 & -16 & -16 \\
21 & 24 & 23 \\
-10 & -12 & -12 \end{bmatrix}$$

I know that $A$ can be represented in the form $A=T^{-1}JT$, where $$T=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and $$J=\begin{bmatrix} 
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Shouldn't the matrix exponential then simply be $T^{-1}e^{Jt}T$? I think this should be correct but Wolfram Alpha gave a [different result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrixexp%28t%20%7B%7B-14%2C-16%2C-16%7D%2C%7B21%2C24%2C23%7D%2C%7B-10%2C-12%2C-12%7D%7D%29). This has terms which involve $e^{4t}$ while the matrix $J$ has no such terms- all its terms should only have $e^{-2t}$ right? And then simple matrix multiplications shouldn't change the powers of the exponent. I am unable to figure out where am I going wrong with this.

Thanks

Comment: The Wolfram Alpha has one eigenvalue of 2 instead of all three being -2.

Answer (score 0):

I obtain
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix} 
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
with

$$T=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}, \quad
T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 
-4 & 3 & -2 \\
5 & -4 & 4 \\
-2 & 2 & -2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
We should indeed have $\exp(T^{-1}JT)=T^{-1}\exp(J)T$.

Do you have the factor $2$ of the last row reflected in your inverse of $T$? You should check again all three matrices, $T^{-1},J,T$. Of course, $T$ is not unique.

Comment: yes I have taken it into account. My inverse is correct.

Comment: So what is your inverse then?

Answer (score 0):

Those terms with $e^{4t}$ vanish after simplifying the expression. For instance, the top left entry of the answer is $-e^{-2t}(4t+2e^{4t}-3)$, which is equal to $-4te^{-2t}-2e^{2t}+3e^{-2t}$.

Comment: I know that but that is the same as the $e^{2t}$ term in your expression. Where is that coming from then?

Comment: Your matrix $J$ is wrong. It should be$$J=\begin{bmatrix}-2&1&0\\0&-2&0\\0&0&\color{red}2\end{bmatrix}.$$